# Alternative to restarting Super Mario Bros Wii U

Tags: new-super-mario-bros-u

I am playing Super Mario Bros Wii U. When I perform badly on a level, and perhaps loose whatever power up I may have, I find it necessary to quit, and restart from the previous good save state. This is a frustrating and time consuming process, is there any easier way to undo mistakes? I am sure I am missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The levels are meant to be replayed.  Just work your way to the end of the stage starting from the checkpoint, and then play it again when you want to find the extra goodies.